# Ajax request with CORS redirect fails in IE11

Tags: ajax, redirect, cors

I'm trying to make an ajax request to a resource on the same domain. Under certain circumstances the request gets redirected(303) to an external resource. The external resource supports CORS.

In browsers like Chrome, Firefox or Safari the request succeeds.
In IE11 the request fails with error:

```
SCRIPT 7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x4c7, The operation was canceled by the user
```

The ajax request is made with jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/data",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
  data: JSON.stringify({name: 'John Doe'})
}).done(function () {
  console.log('succeeded');
}).fail(function () {
  console.log('failed');
});
```

I've build a little [example](http://test-xhr-redirect-robs0n.c9users.io/) which demonstrates the problem. You could see the code [here](https://c9.io/robs0n).

#### w/o redirect

[image: w/o redirect]

#### w/ redirect

[image: w/ redirect]

Is there a way to solve this problem? What am I missing?

Comment: I've faced the same issue - some updates about this one?

Comment: This is a very specific question that specifically matches the scenario I am seeing.    Does anyone have any thoughts on this particular scenario

Comment: @NickHarrison Have a look at my response below I think it might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43410576/7199519.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the initial definition of the CORS-standard, redirects after a successful CORS-preflight request were not allowed.

IE11 implements this (now outdated) standard.

Since August 2016, this has changed, and all major browsers now support it (Here's the actual [pull request](https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/commit/0d9a4db8bc02251cc9e391543bb3c1322fb882f2)).

I'm afraid to support <=IE11 you'll have to modify your server-side code as well to not issue a redirect (at least for <=IE11).

**Part 1) Server-side (I'm using node.js express here):**

```
function _isIE (request) {
  let userAgent = request.headers['user-agent']
  return userAgent.indexOf("MSIE ") > 0 || userAgent.indexOf("Trident/") > 0
}

router.post('data', function (request, response) {
  if (_isIE(request)) {
    // perform action
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
    return res.status(200).send(`${redirectionTarget}`)
  } else {
    // perform action
    response.redirect(redirectionTarget)
  }
})
```

**Part 2 Client-side**

Note: This is pure Javascript, but you can easily adapt it to your jQuery/ajax implementation.

```
var isInternetExplorer = (function () {
  var ua = window.navigator.userAgent
  return ua.indexOf("MSIE ") > 0 || ua.indexOf("Trident/") > 0
})()

function requestResource (link, successFn, forcedRedirect) {
  var http
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    http = new XMLHttpRequest()
  } else if (window.XDomainRequest) {
    http = new XDomainRequest()
  } else {
    http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
  }
  http.onreadystatechange = function () {
    var OK = 200
    if (http.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      if (http.status === OK && successFn)  {
        if (isInternetExplorer && !forcedRedirect) {
          return requestResource(http.responseText, successFn, true)
        } else {
          successFn(http.responseText)
        }
      }
    }
  }
  http.onerror = http.ontimeout = function () {
    console.error('An error occured requesting '+link+' (code: '+http.status+'): '+http.responseText)
  }
  http.open('GET', link)
  http.send(null)
}
```

Comment: We've implemented already a workaround for this. Your suggestion seems also to be quite good. Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score -2):

its already answered - have a look - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/28/sending-a-cors-request-in-ie/

Comment: Sorry, but where is this specific question answered? The link you provide is for how to make a cors request in IE and how IE behaves with cors in generally. This wasn't helpful.